# How can I use Protocols to simulate typing.Collection in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to annotate that a function returns some form of collection, but without being specific about the implementation, so that I'm free to switch between `list`/`tuple`/`set`/`dict.values()` in the future.  In Python 3.6, I'd use [`typing.Collection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Collection):

```
def foo(self) -> Collection[str]:
    return ["bar", "baz"]
```

but Python 3.5 doesn't have it.  The `typing` backport `typing_extensions` doesn't provide it either, as Python 3.5 lacks the underlying `collections.abc.Collection` too.

I'm [not the first](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4517) to raise this question, and Guido van Rossum suggests using the [`Protocol`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544) backport to do it, but doesn't provide many more details.  What would the implementation look like?